# Pulling and displaying API data to tailwind cards

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

could someone help on how to get all data from this console log? I am trying to display all the details in individual tailwind cards but not sure how to get the data. Thank you for your time.

```
  axios.get('https://api.url**.com/api/v1/content/publications',{
      headers: {
       'X-AUTH-TOKEN' : '22***8a8369317***********'
      }
    }
  )

.then(response => { 
   console.log (response.data)
```

It works and I get the results below in console.

[image: array image]

[image: array image 2]

when I tried `console.log (response.data.0.pdf)` for example, it gives an error "Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected".

Is it possible to get all the data under publications into individual cards?

```
<div class="max-w-sm p-6 bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
    <a href="#">
        <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">**{author}**</h5>
    </a>
    <p class="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
**{pdf}**
**{id}**
**{etc}**</p>
    <a href="#" class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">
        Read more
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-4 h-4 ml-2 -mr-1" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.293 3.293a1 1 0 011.414 0l6 6a1 1 0 010 1.414l-6 6a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L14.586 11H3a1 1 0 110-2h11.586l-4.293-4.293a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
    </a>
</div>
```

Thanks again for your time.

Comment: `response.data` is an array, so try `response.data[0].pdf`.

Comment: thank you, that works. could you suggest a doc on how to get all the info at once so I use it within the cards independently? I tried response.data[0,1,2,3].pdf it only returns one at a time and I have 50 to call. thanks again

Comment: Are you wanting to *render* all this data to JSX? You'd need to save the data to some React state and then map the data to the JSX you want to display. Can you [edit] your post to include a more complete [mcve] for what you are trying to do overall in this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell it seems you are *already* fetching all the data since the response is an array. It seems like your question is then *how* to save and render the response data.

1. Create a local state variable to hold the fetched data. When this state is updated React will trigger a rerender with the latest state enclosed in scope.

   ```
   const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
   ```
2. Fetch the data in a component lifecycle method/hook, e.g. `useEffect` when the component mounts, and enqueue a state update to save the fetched data.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     axios.get('https://api.url**.com/api/v1/content/publications',{
       headers: {
        'X-AUTH-TOKEN' : '22***8a8369317***********'
       }
     })
       .then(response => { 
         console.log(response.data);
         setData(response.data); // <-- save response to state
       });
   }, []);
   ```
3. Render the local state to JSX. Arrays are typically *mapped* to JSX, e.g. `Array.prototype.map`. Each mapped element object is accessible in the map callback, e.g. `item.author`. Don't forget to also include a `key` prop on the outer-most mapped element. The React key is used as part of React's reconciliation process when it's computing what needs to refreshed to the DOM.

   ```
   {data.map(item => (
     <div
       key={item.id}
       class="max-w-sm p-6 bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700"
     >
       <a href="#">
         <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
           {item.author}
         </h5>
       </a>
       <p class="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
         {item.pdf}
         {item.id}
         {item.etc}
       </p>
       <a
         href="#"
         class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
       >
         Read more
         <svg
           aria-hidden="true"
           class="w-4 h-4 ml-2 -mr-1"
           fill="currentColor"
           viewBox="0 0 20 20"
           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         >
           <path
             fill-rule="evenodd"
             d="M10.293 3.293a1 1 0 011.414 0l6 6a1 1 0 010 1.414l-6 6a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L14.586 11H3a1 1 0 110-2h11.586l-4.293-4.293a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
             clip-rule="evenodd"
           />
         </svg>
       </a>
     </div>
   ))}
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot Drew! worked for me. For other newbies, the "item" variable needs to be swapped. For me it was "publications" so "publications.author" for example. Now I need to learn how to add a search function the app :)